# Inserting a TextBox causes 1004 error on iOS while works on Windows 10

Tags: ios, excel, vba, addition, ole

I use a VBA macro for Excel (Office 365) that creates dynamically a text box. It works perfectly on Windows 10 but fails on iOS (Office 365 too).

Below I isolated the sample code where function **ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add** fails on iOS with the following error message: *execution error 1004. Cannot insert object*

*Any hint is welcome*

```
Sub AddTextBox()
     Dim oTB, obj As Object
     Set oTB = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1")
End Sub
```

Comment: with `Dim oTB, obj As Object`, `oTB` is set as variant not object: `Dim oTB as Object, obj As Object`

Comment: @ScottCraner that's correct and a good thing to point out and for the OP to fix, but the variant is `Set`-assigned, so the runtime type after the assignment is `Variant/Object`, which is fine. [Is ActiveX enabled](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-activex-settings-in-office-files-f1303e08-a3f8-41c5-a17e-b0b8898743ed) (or even supported, on iOS)?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon sorry, yes, meant to put, that was not the problem, but a recommendation.

Comment: A worksheet is literally *made* of thousands of little textboxes (cells). Have you considered *not* using a `TextBox` control, and naming a specific [merged?] range instead, nicely formatted, with borders and shading?

Comment: Thank you all for answers. @MathieuGuindon Spreadsheet is 2D table with has various content including both short & large fields (larger than max height in Excel). Table is generated by an external system. For easy reading, filterring, sorting, i set fixed height for all rows (single line). For multiline columns,  Upon selection, I create on the fly a well positionned text box with horizontal+vertical scrollbars. This allows easy reading of a cell without destroying table formatting. I use worksheet_selection_change event. Boxes are deleted when selection changes.

Comment: While writing, I think I found a workaround. Instead of creating on the fly the textbox. I could simply create once the textbox and just move its position upon selection change.

Comment: After several tests, it appears any OLE method or property is failing on iOS. Finally, I removed the OLE object and used instead a simple rectangle shape with the AutoFit to text option.